LFS refusing to upload electron.exe file even though .exe files are already added in its track-list
Trying to upload an elctronJS project with an electron.exe file using lfs but being given the error:
Git LFS upload failed:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s
  (missing) client/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe (b6ca93423ea17b17f7a60af3ec663b61746245f2b2ec87673f810a7d14328fcf)
hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects.
hint: You can disable this check with: `git config lfs.allowincompletepush true`

Tried re-installing lfs.
Uploaded the project without the .exe file and later tried to add it afterwards:
git add -f client/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe

then committed:
git commit -m "Re-add electron.exe to Git LFS"

which resulted in no errors.
But during the final push, got the error shown above.

You can try to remove the LFS cache by running "git lfs prune".
